# pycharm pandas datareader unable to import duyf=f]dai;sad'lsahildsalj;dasli

Tags: pandas, datareader

I'm in a process of learning python for algotrade and finance.
I use the pycharm community.
watching a codealong course, and i have a problem, can't import pandas_datareader.
this is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import pandas_datareader as pdr
```

i got that error:
No module named 'pandas_datareader'
even when I try to install it via pip:

I need it to import pandas_datareader for financial data.

Comment: Are you getting errors when you install it with pip? Make sure you're using a dash instead of an underscore - per the documentation (https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) you install with a dash, `pip install pandas-datareader` but import with an underscore in your script `import pandas_datareader as pdr`